# .load() makes .button( "refresh" ) stop working

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a large section of code that I am using `$('.data').prop('checked', false).button("refresh");` in to uncheck and refresh the jQuery UI styling on a group of checkboxes with data as their class. It works fine up until my code runs `$("#div").load('output.php')` which refreshes the output.php file. After this point, .prop('checked', false) works fine, but .button("refresh") stops working.

So what happens is the checkboxes keep unchecking properly, but the jQuery UI style doesn't refresh so they appear to stay checked even though they are not. Output.php is included on the page to start with, and I tried replacing the load with `$("#div").load('text.txt')` but it still stops working even if it is just loading the text file.

So it seems that .load() is breaking .button("refresh"). Any ideas what could be causing that or any potential solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content that I was loading was html and had a `<head>` section. This was what was breaking .button("refresh"). I took what was in the head and included it in my main page's head and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is .data within #div? If so, the content of output.php will replace it, and the replaced elements will not carry the jQuery UI event data, as it was never bound to them.

Comment: Odd. Must have broken a selector in jQuery UI by having 2 head tags. Non-compliant code can create odd results. Plugin authors should be able to assume there will only be one head/body tag etc for example.